# Android WorkManager working with debug build but not with release APK

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My WorkManager version: 1.0.0-beta01

I'm using both one time work and periodic work.
Everything is working as expected in debug build.

But when I create signed release APK, both the one time and periodic works are not executing.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: You need to find the difference between debug and release, e.g. the `minifiedEnabled` flag, source code differences.

Comment: @shizhensource code is same. For release build minifiedEnabled was true. I remove minifiedEnabled  for release build and retried, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the definition of my worker class. It was defined like this:

```
class MyWorker extends Worker {
}
```

Changing the class definition to below:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
}
```

Fixed my problem with release APK.